# How to convert a `f64` to a `f32`?

Tags: rust, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

How can I convert a `f64` into the closest `f32`?

There is neither a `From` nor a `TryFrom` implementation, presumably because such implementations are only provided for lossless conversions. I also searched for references to `f32` in the `f64` docs and vice versa, and found nothing.

```rust
    let double: f64 = 0.;

    // doesn't work
    // let single: f32 = double.into();
    // let single: f32 = double.try_into().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, we can use the `as` keyword for casting. It is usually not desired for integer conversions because "casting from a larger integer to a smaller integer (e.g. u32 -> u8) will truncate", and this is usually not wanted. For `f64` to `f32`, however, it's very sensible:

> Casting from an f64 to an f32 will produce the closest possible f32
>
> - if necessary, rounding is according to roundTiesToEven mode
> - on overflow, infinity (of the same sign as the input) is produced
>
> [*Rust Reference*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions)

```rust
    let double: f64 = 42.;
    dbg!(double as f32);
```

```
[src/main.rs:13] double as f32 = 42.0
```

If an overflow to infinity is not desired and you want to panic instead, the simplest solution might be to check for `is_finite`:

```rust
fn f64_to_f32(x: f64) -> f32 {
    let y = x as f32;
    assert_eq!(
        x.is_finite(),
        y.is_finite(),
        "f32 overflow during conversion"
    );
    y
}
```

```rust
fn main() {
    dbg!(f64_to_f32(42_f64));
    // dbg!(f64_to_f32(f64::MAX / 10.)); // panics
    dbg!(f64_to_f32(f64::NAN));
    dbg!(f64_to_f32(f64::INFINITY));
    dbg!(f64_to_f32(f64::NEG_INFINITY));
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:2] f64_to_f32(42_f64) = 42.0
[src/main.rs:4] f64_to_f32(f64::NAN) = NaN
[src/main.rs:5] f64_to_f32(f64::INFINITY) = inf
[src/main.rs:6] f64_to_f32(f64::NEG_INFINITY) = -inf
```